# how to make a tab in chrome into a live chat window

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, chat

I would like to make a tab in Google Chrome (http://web.whatsapp.com) into a live chat window so that it is separate from other chrome tabs, similar to [this](http://cloud.addictivetips.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/GChat-Pix1.jpg).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to seperate a tab from the main window and create a new one, all you have to do is:

1. Click and hold on the tab you want to seperate.
2. Drag the tab away from the top bar that contains the tabs.
3. Release the tab wherever you want Google Chrome to spawn a new window.

However, in order to make it into a popup window like in your screenshot, you would have to add an extension to Google Chrome.  I personally like [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/open-as-popup/ncppfjladdkdaemaghochfikpmghbcpc?hl=en) extension, as it is a one-click solution.